# Content from JSON file not displaying when trying to access via vue file

Tags: vue.js

When I click my 'Read More' button which is located in the RecipesPage.vue, the contents of my JSON file don't display. I've looked all over but I've not been able to find something similar enough to apply to this project.

I've tried using axios, fetch, and vue router and none of it is working. When I was using axios, I was getting a 404 error. With fetch and vue router, I just get a blank page. The browser console gives me a warning: [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "id". Expected Number with value 1, got String with value "1". I've tried `params: { id: +post.id } }"` and `params: { id: Number(post.id) } }"`, but neither of those worked either.

Here is some of my code. Any insight would be much appreciated.

RecipesPage.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="container mt-4">
    <h1 class="text-center mb-4 text-aqua">Welcome to My Recipe Blog</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div
        class="col-md-6 mb-4 text-center d-flex align-items-center"
        v-for="post in blogPosts"
        :key="post.id"
      >
        <div class="card text-aqua">
          <img
            :src="require(`@/assets/${post.imageFileName}`)"
            class="card-img-top blog-thumbnail mx-auto"
            alt="recipe image"
          />
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column h-100 justify-content-between">
              <h2 class="card-title text-30bfbf">{{ post.title }}</h2>
              <p class="card-text">{{ post.excerpt }}</p>
              <router-link
                :to="{ name: 'PostDetails', params: { id: +post.id } }"
                class="btn btn-primary"
              >
                Read More
              </router-link>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "RecipesPage",
  data() {
    return {
      blogPosts: [
        {
          id: 1,
          title: "Swedish Meatball Sauce",
          excerpt: "Delicious sauce to put over meatballs, pasta, etc.",
          imageFileName: "SwedishMeatballs.jpg",
          content: "Sauce: ...",
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: "Air Fryer Meatballs",
          excerpt:
            "Have them alone or mix them in with the swedish meatball recipe.",
          imageFileName: "fried-meatballs.jpg",
          content: "Recipe follows...",
        },
        // Add more blog posts here
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

PostDetails.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="container mt-4" v-if="post">
    <div class="card text-aqua">
      <img
        :src="require(`@/assets/${post.imageFileName}`)"
        class="card-img-top post-image blog-thumbnail"
        alt="recipe image"
      />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h2 class="card-title text-30bfbf">{{ post.title }}</h2>
        <p class="card-text">{{ post.excerpt }}</p>
        <div class="card-text">{{ post.content }}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "PostDetails",
  props: {
    id: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      post: null,
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.fetchPostData();
  },
  methods: {
    async fetchPostData() {
      try {
        const response = await fetch("/posts.json");
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
        }
        const posts = await response.json();

        this.post = posts.find((post) => post.id === this.id);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching post data:", error);
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

index.js

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
import HomePage from "../pages/HomePage.vue";
import AboutPage from "../pages/AboutPage.vue";
import RecipesPage from "../pages/RecipesPage.vue";

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "home",
    component: HomePage,
  },
  {
    path: "/about",
    name: "about",
    component: AboutPage,
  },
  {
    path: "/recipes",
    name: "recipes",
    component: RecipesPage,
  },
  {
    path: "/post/:id",
    name: "PostDetails",
    component: () => import("../components/PostDetails.vue"),
    props: true,
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
  linkExactActiveClass: "pink-active", // Set the class for active links
});

export default router;
```

posts.json (in public folder)

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Swedish Meatball Sauce",
        "excerpt": "Delicious sauce to put over meatballs, pasta, etc.",
        "imageFileName": "SwedishMeatballs.jpg",
        "content": "Sauce: ..."
      }
      ,
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Air Fryer Meatballs",
      "excerpt": "Have them alone or mix them in with the swedish meatball recipe.",
      "imageFileName": "fried-meatballs.jpg",
      "content": "Recipe follows..."
    }
  ]
```

Comment: I don't understand, in the title, it says the content of a file is not displaying, but the description is about a route that is not resolving. Is that right?

Comment: I can’t figure it out. It seems the route resolves okay, because the url changes to the post id that I am calling but no content displays. I’m not sure what exactly is or isn’t happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content is not displaying because of the prop error. Without a valid prop id, your code that finds the correct recipe doesn't work. Fixing the error will fix the content not displaying.

The key is knowing your router params become your URL params. Specifying `props: true` takes the **URL params** and applies them as the component prop values. URL always being a string, the params are also always strings, unless you cast the params in your route definition:

```js
{
  path: "/post/:id",
  name: "PostDetails",
  component: PostDetails,
  props: (route) => {
    return { ...route.params, id: Number(route.params.id) };
  }
}
```

Now id will always be cast as a Number prop.

P.S. adding `...router.params` is for in case you add more props in the future that don't need specific casting, but is technically not needed while `id` remains your only prop.

Comment: That was perfect! Thanks for your help, that was a super quick and easy fix.